# Tablet battery connector identification

Tags: batteries, connector

[image: GoClever Insignia 1010 Tablet battery connector]

Can anybody identify this connector type? 
It's from my tablet. Low Profile

Comment: Did you not see my answer? or non-answer according to Nick

Answer (score 0):

It's called a 4S cell balancer cable plug.  But there may be different shells and pitches.

[image]

This is your connector  Micro JST SH 1.0mm Pitch ( with cable)
[image]

Yours may be a different pitch. Measure it.
http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSH.pdf

- JST HR family is 2.5mm pitch http://www.jst.com/home21.html
- the left column indicates the wire pitch in mm
  http://www.jst.com/home21.html

Without measurements, and more effort on your side, this is all that I can offer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65737/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-ee-since-75-tablet-battery-connector-iden).